# How to set up auto deployment of a maven project on multiple machines?

Tags: java, automation, perforce, maven-release-plugin

I have a maven project that lives in 3 servers/hosts.

I was looking at the  [maven release plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) but I cant seem to find how to push to multiple servers at the same time. BTW my source control is Perforce.
I wanted to see if I can deploy the project to multiple locations(servers/hosts) during the mvn package cycle and avoid the manual transfer of the jars to these different machines.

Can somebody point me to some documentation that discusses this?

Comment: rewrite question to make it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this, I created different profiles for each deployment in the POM similar to the following

```
 <profile>
    <id>deployToDev_Host</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>dev</name>
                <value>test</value>
            </property>
        </activation>

        <build>
            <plugins> 
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>restart_service</id>
                            <phase>deploy</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <target>

                                    <scp trust="yes" file="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar" remoteToFile="location/on/remote/host/" />
            </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>                        
    </profile>
```

Followed this document   http://slackspace.de/articles/create-deployment-profiles-with-maven/